# TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add, when using np.average

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that computes an weighted average based on two columns of a pandas dataframe.

```
import numpy as np

df3 = {
      'ID': ['XhspIudYY5', 'm6Xi6Y2yMi', 'GDD7kFZKTv', '0rWWmnUfrv', 'ptsFJODIsC'],
      'weights': [100, 99.760477, 99.480757, 90.216866, 99.940069],
      'value': [42.98, 32.5, 43.65, 44.43, 40.28]
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(df3, columns = ['ID', 'weights', 'value'])
calc = round(np.average(df['value'], weights = df['weights']),2)
print(calc)
```

The DataFrame is manipulated and new row is added and a new average is calculated. When this happens, it throws an error:

```
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/file.py", line 946, in update_graph
    result = calc(var1, var2...)
  File "/Users/Deploy/calc.py", line 220, in calc_rent
    calc = round(np.average(df['value'], weights = df['weights']),2)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in average
    
  File "/Users/../lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 407, in average
    scl = wgt.sum(axis=axis, dtype=result_dtype)
  File "/Users/../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 47, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add
```

Comment: when I fix a typo it works.  `df3 = {...` instead of `df = {...`. value of *calc* is *40.7*

Comment: typo is not the issue.

Comment: point is there is no issue - the code just runs and gives the result...  I suspect `df` is not what you expect.  plus your example is not a dataframe but a dict

Comment: missed a line to turn dict into a dataframe. yeah, I guess there are instances when I manipulate the dataframe by adding a new row with values that throws this error. I am looking for help on why the numpy function/python would throw this error.